# AJAX suddenly not functioning in Wordpress site

Tags: ajax, wordpress

A site I built back in November has been using AJAX to pull in content on a single page in Wordpress up until now. After the page loads initially and the static content appears, when a user clicks a name in a list, the static content is replaced with content pulled from a directory via AJAX. About two weeks ago, when a user clicks a name in that list, the static content disappears, but is not replaced. AJAX seems to be broken...? It's a Wordpress install. I have the same exact functionality working successfully on a "sister site" of the same nature.

The page can be found here: http://www.cleanse-nyc.com/?page_id=98

This is the code:

```
<div id="teamMenu">
    <ul id="wCoach">
        <h2>CLEANSE Wellness Coaches</h2>

        <li class="hidden"><a href="#" intPage="http://www.cleanse-nyc.com/wp-content/themes/cleanse/FernandadelaPuente.php">Fernanda de la Puente</a></li>

    </ul>
```

By clicking the name in the anchor tag, the relative content should appear using AJAX.

I've tried using Dev Tools to work out the issue, but I'm not seeing anything specific to the issue.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: You need to some how make this question more QA friendly.  Post the JS errors, as well as a subset of markup.  If not this question only helps you.

Comment: Fair enough. Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the guide:  http://jquerytools.org/documentation/performance.html  it will explain that you need to either use full (and not include jquery), or alias $

> GET http://cleansenyc.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/08/cleanse-team-bkg-pvt.jpg 404 (Not Found) www.cleanse-nyc.com:75
>   XHR finished loading: "http://www.cleanse-nyc.com/wp-content/themes/cleanse/AndreaMitchell.php". jquery.tools.min.js:38
>   Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Right now jquery tools is using $.  I would suggest you update the line

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

to

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

---

Alternatively the better fix is to use the bundled jquery.  There is one with a /full that will load the tools,and automatically import jquery.js

e.g.  current version

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Will import both jquery and jquery tools.

Comment: I've checked that, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. If you see it in use here [link](http://www.cleanse-amsterdam.com/?page_id=90), it's perfectly fine. For some reason, the reference to the PHP file is not being fulfilled. Literally stopped working out of the blue.

Comment: the bundled jQuery? What do you mean by that? Wordpress includes jQuery in the install.

Comment: i tested it in console, and all your links work, by magically setting $ = jQuery.  Not the right solution, but it is a solution.

Comment: I updated jQuery Tools to not include jQuery in the bundle and am loading it from my server instead of theirs. Where I've got var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); can I also add var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); below it? Is that legit?

Comment: Done. Works. Thank you @nix. Made my day.